# Reading structured column data with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So I'm trying to use the following to read the following file with numpy:

```
import numpy as np

recordtype = np.dtype([('name', 'S24'),
                       ('ra', [(np.int32,np.int32,np.float32)]),
                       ('dec', [(np.int32,np.int32,np.float32)]),
                        ('z',np.float32), ('rmag',np.float32),('rmag_error',np.float32),
                        ('gmag',np.float32),('gmag_error',np.float32)])
qData = numpy.loadtxt("SDSS_quasar_cat5(1)", skiprows=6)
```

Here's a sample of the datafile:

```
Results from heasarc_sdssquasar: Sloan Digital Sky Survey Quasar Catalog (10th Data Release: DR10Q)
Coordinate system:  Equatorial
|name                    |ra          |dec         |vi_redshift|rmag        |rmag_error  |gmag     |gmag_error  |
|SDSS J163313.26+352050.7|16 33 13.265|+35 20 50.77|     2.0000|2.480190e+01|3.865410e+00|2.511420e+01|9.026890e-01|
|SDSS J164135.36+372726.9|16 41 35.362|+37 27 26.96|     2.0000|2.279110e+01|1.722010e-01|2.203690e+01|7.126500e-02|
|SDSS J160420.86+275634.5|16 04 20.869|+27 56 34.52|     2.0010|2.008330e+01|2.592250e-02|2.048210e+01|2.699570e-02|
|SDSS J163948.06+331030.2|16 39 48.069|+33 10 30.27|     2.0010|1.945350e+01|1.478850e-02|1.971600e+01|1.617890e-02|
|SDSS J162006.83+395403.8|16 20 06.834|+39 54 03.83|     2.0020|1.937250e+01|2.033600e-02|1.942160e+01|2.408500e-02|
```

I can't seem to get past defining the dtype. I'm new to python, and looked for examples, but I must have something wrong. Any suggestions?

Thx!

Comment: With your example code I get a `TypeError: data type not understood`. That's because of the Right Ascension and Declination definitions: aside from (fixed length) strings, you can only use discrete types for each field

Comment: Rats -- does that mean I have to read the 2 integers and one float (for RA and Dec) as separate arrays?

Comment: Or you can convert them to decimal degrees. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Well that's what I want to get to, but I don't have control over the data file if that's what you mean. I have to read Hr, Min, Sec and then convert them... I'm still stuck on just reading the dang file!! I don't know how to use loadtxt and dtype yet!

Comment: Yeah, yeah... Well you can provide "converters" for each column if needed. Let me write down a short example so that you can see how is it done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example.

```
import numpy as np

recordtype = np.dtype([('name', 'S24'),
                       ('ra', np.float32),
                       ('dec', np.float32),
                       ('z',np.float32),
                       ('rmag',np.float32),
                       ('rmag_error',np.float32), 
                       ('gmag',np.float32),
                       ('gmag_error',np.float32)])

def ratodeg(string):
    hh, mm, ss = string.split()

    return (int(hh) * 15) + (int(mm) * 0.25) + (float(ss)  * 0.0042)

def dectodeg(string):
    return 

qData = np.loadtxt("sample",
                   skiprows=1,
                   dtype=recordtype,
                   delimiter = '|',
                   usecols = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
                   converters = {1:str,
                                 2:ratodeg,
                                 3:dectodeg})
```

Note a few things in the call to `loadtxt`:

1. The use of `dtype` to specify the right one. Otherwise NumPy will assume you want an array of floats
2. The use of `delimiter` to tell `loadtxt` how to break the columns
3. The `usecolumns` to specify which ones to use. Column `0` and `9` are the blanks before the first | and after the last one
4. The use of `converters`. It assigns converter functions for each specified column. Only addressed columns 1-3. The default converter is `float(...)`

I left `dectodeg` blank because I can't ever remember on top of my head how to do the conversion :P (I'm not even sure `ratodeg` is ok...), so right now `dec` is `nan` for each row.

Comment: Thx Ricardo! I'm gonna give it a try! Didn't know about converters.

Comment: Worked beautifully Ricardo... Thank you.

Comment: That's the truth... Hey, I'm a c++ guy too. Pro software developer who's back in school to become an astronomer! Thx again for the help.